# Managing multiple requirements.txt dependencies

Tags: python, pip, package

I use two package list files for installation.

requirements.txt: generic dependency package

requirements.me-*.txt: dev ( git+https://some url)

The order of installation is 1 → 2.

Currently, requirements.txt have the following versions: a==12.0.0, which are different versions from those used in dev. (dev is a==14.0.0)

In this case, a==12.0.0 is installed first, and when dev is installed, a==12.0.0 is deleted and a==14.0.0 is reinstalled.
Unnecessary installation/deletion increases CI time.

Is there a better way to manage dependencies?

Should packages installed in dev simply be removed from requirements.txt?

Comment: Split `requirements.txt` into `requirements-common.txt`. Include `requirements-common.txt` into `requirements.txt` and `requirements-dev.txt` using [`-r requirements-common.txt`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#referring-to-other-requirements-files).

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you explain it in more detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split `requirements.txt` into `requirements-common.txt`. Put everything except `a` into `requirements-common.txt`. Put `a==12.0.0` into `requirements.txt`. Put `a==14.0.0` into `requirements-dev.txt`.

Include `requirements-common.txt` into `requirements.txt` and `requirements-dev.txt` using `-r requirements-common.txt`. These 3 files should look like this:

`requirements-common.txt`:

```
dependencies
dependencies
dependencies
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
-r requirements-common.txt
a==12.0.0
```

`requirements-dev.txt`:

```
-r requirements-common.txt
a==14.0.0
```

Now install using either `pip install -r requirements.txt` or `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt`. The former installs `requirements-common.txt` + `a==12`, the latter `requirements-common.txt` + `a==14`.